# How strong wind is needed for crop lodging?

Tags: agriculture

I'm making a science project to protect the crops from wind lodging by placing some shields beside the field only when needed (wind have beneficial effects on crops). I want to use some sensors like anemometer to measure the wind velocity and direction to detect whether protection shield is needed.

But I can't figure out where to find the information that what is the minimum velocity of air to lodge crops. I know it will depend on which type of crop we're cultivating e.g. rice, jute, corn etc. I want to use just any one of these to demonstrate in my science project.

Comment: Do you have access to any scientific literature? I found this which have models for Oats, Wheat and Oilseed rape : https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jtbi.2014.07.032 - they indicate velocity for the above mentioned crops.

Comment: Can you edit your question and clarify the sentence ' want to use some sensors like anemometer to detect the it.' especially the *it*

Comment: No I don't have access to any scientific literature. Is there any alternative sources?

Comment: I am not a soil scientist - it seems like the models presented in the paper I mentioned are quite elaborated. I can't at this time summarize properly the concepts presented there. Maybe someone else?